# _post_put_hook in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Python `ndb.Model` has a convenient `_post_put_hook` where you can perform some work after the entity is saved to the datastore.
Since models in Go are just structs, how is this feature supported?

Answer (score 1):

App engine datastore operations take `PropertyLoadSaver` interface as an input. For example, `datastore.Put` has the following signature:

```
func Put(c context.Context, key *Key, src interface{}) (*Key, error)
```

With the following documentation about `src`:

> Put saves the entity src into the datastore with key k. src must be a
>   struct pointer or implement PropertyLoadSaver

This means that you can implement your own custom behavior around various datastore operations. An example can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface).

Comment: This would be a `pre_put`, not a `post_put`.

Comment: In your `Save` interface method for your entity, you'll be calling `datastore.SaveStruct` function at some point. Whatever post put operation you need, it can go after this call, depending on it success status.

Comment: No, you don't necessary call the SaveStruct - see example at docs - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface.  And even if you do call it does not save to DB - just serialize to slice of properties.https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#SaveStruct
So in no way it's an analogue of _post_put. To have a _post_put I guess you  you would need a wrapper over API and use it everywhere.

Comment: oh i see.. my bad. I didn't realize that's simply for custom serialization.